# Encrypt Tablet function in Android x86. Android 6 in Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, encryption, android-x86

I am currently running Android x86 version 6 in Oracle Virtual Box.

My intention is to run some software my company creates and to test it without the need for a physical tablet.

The software i install requires the tablet to be encrypted using the Settings -> Security -> Encrypt Tablet feature in Android.

However all i get is the OS reboots and no encryption happens.

So i have two questions:

1. Can i get encryption to work?
2. Is there a way to fool the software into thinking that encryption has worked and not actually encrypt it?

The reason the software wants an encrypted device is that in the real world the device will store customer and financial data. In my test system its all fake data so i dont care about encryption.

Comment: Android x86 is IMHO not a good platform for testing software as it is a simple community project. I strongly recommend to use the Android emulator with Google provided images instead, or best a real physical tablet. Otherwise your test results are not very realistic and reliable.

Comment: @Robert Do you have a link where i can get the recommended Google images and Android emulator? I require Android 6.0

Comment: Install Android SDK or Android Studio. Use the AVD manager and select and Android 6 image.

Comment: @Robert None of the ARM images will run from Android Studio. They all hang on the Android starting logo. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not use ARM images in an emulator, only use x86 images. Also make sure your CPU supports virtualization and install the appropriate virtualization helper tools (Intel HAXM/AMD Hypervisor driver). Both are available via Android SDK maanger.